# Doctrine, Zend, Entity QueryException has no field or association named

Tags: exception, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm having an OrderEntity. First time i just needed three properties from the table. But now I need two more. 
So I'm adding this two properties to my entity:

```
namespace Stock\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="orders")
 */
class OrderEntity
{
/** 
 * @ORM\Id 
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="orders_id")
 */
private $ordersId;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="order_number") 
 */
private $orderNumber;

/** 
* @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="stores_id")
*/
private $storesId;

/** 
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=3, name="currency")
*/
private $currency;

/** 
* @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=6, scale=14, name="currency_value")
*/
private $currencyValue;


public function getOrdersId()
{
    return $this->ordersId;
}

public function setOrdersId($ordersId)
{
    $this->ordersId = $ordersId;
}

public function getOrderNumber()
{
    return $this->orderNumber;
}

public function setOrderNumber($orderNumber)
{
    $this->orderNumber = $orderNumber;
}

public function getStoresId()
{
    return $this->storesId;
}

public function setStoresId($storesId)
{
    $this->storesId = $storesId;
}

public function getCurrency() 
{
    return $this->currency;
}

public function getCurrencyValue() 
{
    return $this->currencyValue;
}

public function setCurrency($currency) 
{
    $this->currency = $currency;
    return $this;
}

public function setCurrencyValue($currencyValue) 
{
    $this->currencyValue = $currencyValue;
    return $this;
}
```

The new properties are the currency and currencyValue.

```
$query = $this->getEm()->createQuery(
            "SELECT o.ordersId, o.currency FROM "
            . "Stock\Entity\OrderEntity o WHERE "
            . "o.ordersId ='".$orderId."'"
        );
```

If I want to create a query with using the newer properties I got a QueryException:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 21 near 'currency FROM': Error: Class     Stock\Entity\OrderEntity has no field or association named currency
```

I don't exactly understand where the problem is!

Comment: By using this query just with the ordersId Property the query works fine

Comment: Forget my post. After restarting apache the property could be found. It's magic :D

Comment: Not magic.  Anytime you change schema stuff you will need to do some sort of cache clearing process.  If each request had to completely regenerate all the doctrine mapping information then performance would suffer considerably.  Hence the caching.  You might also want to write an answer to your own question.  That will save other people from reading through an already answered question.

Comment: Or you can just delete your question.